# Symfony2.1: email sent in HTML format seems to be escaped

Tags: symfony, html-email, symfony-2.1, swiftmailer

In my **Symfony2.1** application I'm using the **SwiftMailer** to send emails. Since I'm in *dev mode*, I'm not sending emails for reals. I control the output in the toolbar provided by the *Profiler*.

The email I'm sending is in HTML. So, to ensure HTML output I did the following settings:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setContentType("text/html")
        ->setSubject('Conferma registrazione nuovo utente')
        ->setFrom('xxx@xxx.com')
        ->setTo($email)
        ->setBody($this->renderView('AcmeMessageBundle:Contact:contact_request_email.html.twig', 'text/html');

$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

I suppose all the setting for HTML emails are ok. Notwithstanding that, I see that the emails sent are not shown as HTML in the Profiler dedicated area. In particular, all the HTML tags are escaped! Why? What am I missing in the settings?

Comment: You should first try sending the email and see what happens I think.

Comment: I would, but I'm in local with Xampp. If someone used Symfony2 to send emails in dev mode would know if html emails are shown as html or as escaped html (i.e. pure text). Do you had any experience?

Comment: For dev you should use something like [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html).

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper Hey, I did it and the email is sent in HTML format! Why the Profiler doesn't display HTML emails? This is incredible. Thanks a lot! Please, consider to post a detailed answer, I will accept it in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dev it is recommended to set up something like [Gmail](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html) to deal with emails

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username:  your_gmail_username
    password:  your_gmail_password
```

As for HTML emails, I can't tell exactly what's your problem, it could be anything. HTML emails are not easy (it's like developing for IE6), that's why a lot of devs just choose to send text emails.